# How can I add a function to an object and reference its members?

Tags: javascript

I've got a class:

```
var MyClass = function(property, function){
    var me = this;

    me.property = property;
    me.function = function;
};
```

In another place, I'd like to add a function which references the class property, like so:

```
var myClass = new MyClass({
    property: 5,
    function: function(){
        // do something with this.property
    }
});
```

The `this` keyword doesn't reference the object. Is there a way I can set this up so that I can access the property I've set through my passed in anonymous function?

Comment: function is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass two arguments as two variables, not as an object, because your class doesn't expect an object.

```
var myClass = new MyClass('some_property', function(){
    alert(this.property);
});
```

Also, don't use `function` keyword as argumemt, [**Check this example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/fVuE4/) Code given below

```
var MyClass = function(prop, func){
    var me = this;
    me.prop = prop;
    me.func = func;
};

var myClass = new MyClass('some_property', function(){
    alert(this.prop);
});

myClass.func();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here.

First, `function` is a reserved word in JavaScript, so it cannot be used as a var name. Reserved words: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Second, you are passing an object literal instead of the two expected parameters. So for the myClass var statement:

```
var myClass = new MyClass(5, function() { // do something with this.property });
```

I would also recommend not using `property` as a variable name since it's a bit confusing as well.